# Syntax error, Hello World example. Begin ... End

Tags: mysql, functions

I borrow an example hello world function for mysql, but it throws me an error, I don't know where is the syntax error in my query.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS helloWorld;

CREATE FUNCTION helloWorld( s char(20)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT("Hello ", s);
END;

SELECT helloWorld("Albert");
```

*MYSQL Version:* **5.7.21**

> ERROR: [ERROR en la consulta 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 4

If I do the query without BEGIN ... END It works, but I can't do the query without more than 1 line of body.

Comment: Seems to work: http://rextester.com/MYKVVA37097

Comment: Seems to happen only in my DB.

Comment: What interface do you use?

Comment: SQLPRO for mac, I've post an answer with the solution, It works.

Comment: Yes, using delimiters is the proper way when creating procedures/functions/triggers.

Comment: this should be closed as too localized/unclear what is being asked. my guess is it's SQLPRO (whatever that is)

Comment: @EvanCarroll it could be the other way round. That rextester is adding delimiters behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like mysql is confused about the delimeter.

The delimeter for RETURN CONCAT("Hello ", s); is ";".

The delimeter for the query is ";"

I had to change the delimeter to "//" get a good query and change it again to ";".

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS helloWorld;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION helloWorld(s char(20))
   RETURNS CHAR(50)
   BEGIN

     RETURN CONCAT("Hello ", s);
   END; //

DELIMITER ;

SELECT helloWorld("Albert");
```

I don't know why, but this is happening only in my DB.

Comment: Just to bring it down here as well, as noted in the comments on the question, MySQL does require that you use a different delimiter to define the block of code for a stored program (procedures, functions, etc.) from that in use to terminate the lines *inside* that code block. In other dialects (MS SQL Server, for example), it's the difference between a line terminator and a batch terminator; not sure if that's true for MySQL or not.